# How would I approach the following question?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

"Suppose we calculate the vowel value of a word based on the following rubric:

a - 5 points
e - 4 points
i - 3 points
o - 2 points
u - 1 points"

I did:

https://pastebin.com/gDwRxqG7

```
a = 5
e = 4
i = 3
o = 2
u = 1

input5 = input("enter word")
for letter = a in input5:
 print("+5 points")
for letter = e in input5:
 print("+4 points")
for letter = i in input5:
 print("+3 points")
for letter = o in input5:
 print("+2 points")
for letter = u in input5:
 print("+1 point")
```

Comment: You approach it by writing some code.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you show us what your approach was. What errors you're facing or what the roadblock is?

Comment: @clmno Thanks, edited it.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I edited it now, sorry I'm a bit new.

Comment: Now, what's your question?

Comment: @KlausD. How do I do it? Because this didn't work.

Comment: If it doesn't work give a proper error description. Without it your question is most likely being put on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I'm going to make an assumption that you need to find the final score for a word entered.

Here's the code from my assumption:

```
input5 = input("enter words\n")

score = 0
for letter in input5:
        if letter == 'a':
                score += 5
        elif letter == 'e':
                score += 4
        elif letter == 'i':
                score += 3
        elif letter == 'o':
                score += 2
        elif letter == 'u':
                score += 1

print(score)
```

Your syntax to compare if each `letter` in a word is one of the vowels is wrong. It should be a `double equal to` like `==`. A single `=` is a assigning operator and not a comparator. 
You can change my code if you needed to print `"+5 points"`, `"+4 points"`, etc.